# Factorization of $X^{n}-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, can $X^{n}-1$ ever be written as $g\cdot h$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ with $g$ and $h$ monic and non-constant polynomials with integer coefficients such that $a\cdot g+b \cdot h=1$ for suitable $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$? (Clearly this is possible if we only ask $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$.)

Of course, $X^{n}-1$ factors as the product of the cyclotomic polynimials $\Phi_{d}$ taken over the divisors $d$ of $n$, so we must have $g=\prod_{d\in G}\Phi_{d}$ and $h=\prod_{d\in H}\Phi_{d}$ where $G$ and $H$ are disjoint, non-empty subsets of $D=\{d\in\mathbb{N}|d|n\}$ with $G\cup H=D$.

If $d\in G$ and $e\in H$ then in view of $a\cdot g+b\cdot h=1$ we find that $\Phi_{e}(\zeta_{d})$ must be a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{d}]$. In particular, if $1\in G$ then any prime power $e=p^{r}\in D$ must also be in $G$, as $\Phi_{e}(\zeta_{1})=\Phi_{e}(1)=p$ is not a unit.

Comment: Note that non-existence of $g,h$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^{n}-1)$ being connected, that is, a ring without nontrivial idempotents.

Comment: If $\Phi_{e}(\zeta_{d})=\prod_{k\in (\mathbb{Z}/e)^{*}}(\zeta_{d}-\zeta_{e}^{k})$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{d}]$, its norm $\prod_{j\in (\mathbb{Z}/d)^{*}}\prod_{k\in (\mathbb{Z}/e)^{*}}(\zeta_{d}^{j}-\zeta_{e}^{k})=\pm 1$. Considering this in $\mathbb{C}$ and taking absolute values, this equation comes down to: $\prod_{j\in (\mathbb{Z}/d)^{*}}\prod_{k\in (\mathbb{Z}/e)^{*}}|exp(2\pi ij/d)-exp(2\pi ik/e)|=1$. The problem is reduced to one involving distances between cyclotomic points on the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The answer is that it is not possible, because $\Phi_d$ and $\Phi_{dp}$ are not co-prime modulo $p$. Indeed, $\Phi_{dp}$ is either equal to $\Phi^{p}_d$ or $\Phi^{p-1}_d$ modulo $p$ depending on whether $p|d$ or not.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks, Infinity!